# Can I make Rails' CookieStore use JSON under the hood?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I feel like it should be obvious doing this from reading the documentation, but maybe somebody can save me some time.  We are using Ruby's CookieStore, and we want to share the cookie with another server that is part of our website which is using WCF.  We're already b64-decoding the cookie and we are able to validate the signature (by means of sharing the secret token), all of that is great... but of course the session object is marshalled as a Ruby object, and it's not clear what is the best way to proceed.  We could probably have the WCF application make a call to Ruby and have it unmarshal the object and write it out as JSON, but that seems like it will add an unnecessary layer of complexity to the WCF server.

What I'd really like to do is maybe subclass CookieStore, so that instead of just b64 encoding the session object, it writes the object to JSON and then b64's it.  (And does the reverse on the way back in, of course)  That way, the session token is completely portable, I don't have to worry about Ruby version mismatches, etc.  But I'm having trouble figuring out where to do that.  I thought it would be obvious if I pulled up the source for cookie_store.rb, but it's not (at least not to me).  Anybody want to point me in the right direction?

(Anticipating a related objection: Why the hell do we have two *separate* servers that need to be so intimately coordinated that they share the session cookie?  The short answer: Deadlines.)

**Update**: So from reading the code, I found that when the `MessageVerifier` class gets initialized, [it looks to see if there is an option for `:serializer`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb#L32), and if not it uses `Marshal` by default.  There is already a class called `JSON` that fulfills the same contract, so if I could just pass that in, I'd be golden.

Unfortunately, the `initialize` function for `CookieStore` very specifically [*only* grabs the `:digest` option](http://www.tecweb.inf.puc-rio.br/hyperde/browser/trunk/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb?rev=112#L81) to pass along as the options to `MessageVerifier`.  I don't see an easy way around this...  If I could get it to just pass along that `:serializer` option to the `verifier_for` call, then achieving what I want would literally be as simple as adding `:serializer => JSON` to my session_store.rb.

**Update 2**: A co-worker found [this](https://gist.github.com/jeffyip/4091166), which appears to be exactly what I want.  I haven't gotten it to work yet, though...  getting a (bah-dump) stack overflow.  Will update once again if I find anything worthy of note, but I *think* that link solves my problem.

Comment: Agh, I just realized the cookie_store.rb I was looking at was from Rails 2.

Comment: For cookie based session store this might help ... https://gist.github.com/jeffyip/4091166